# How to do sum + cardinality together in aggregation in Elastic search, like sum(distinct target) with distinct( sum(amount)))

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Datatable:

target        amount

10             10000

10             10000

15             12000

15             12000

Expected out put is :

target        amount

1             10000

1             12000

I wanted to achieve the above result in aggregation in elastic search.
Some thing like below but cardinality and sum cant be used together...

"accessorials": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "invoicedt",
            "interval": "week",
            "format": "Y-MM-dd:w",
            "keyed": true
          },
          "aggs": {
            "net_amount": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "netamt"
              }
            },
            "distinct_trknumber": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "target"
              },
              "sum": {
                "field": "amount"
              }
            }
          }
        }

Comment: Do you expect to get `iPhone, 25, 46000` ?

Comment: Given the table you're showing do you expect to get `iPhone, 25, 46000` as a result?

Comment: It's probably better that you add all this directly into your question, it'll be more legible

Comment: Hi, i hope u understand my question now, in the table in description, i am trying to fetch count of distinct target, in addition to the amount and note amount is considered only once for a target.

Comment: @AshaLodhi Suppose if your data is 10 10000, 10 10000, 10 12000. What will be the output?

Comment: hi jaspreet, O/p will be : Count(distinct (10)) - 1 & amount - 10000 Count(distinct (15)) - 1 & amount - 12000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terms aggregation can be used to  get distinct target and amount

**Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "targets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "target",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "amount": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "amount",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "amount"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "targets" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 10,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "amount" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 10000,
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "count" : {
                  "value" : 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 15,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "amount" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 12000,
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "count" : {
                  "value" : 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```